# Take a particular Annotation's data to next view

Tags: ios, dictionary, annotations

I need to set the custom image fetched from webService to the mapPins.For this i write a particular code in the method

```
   - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation Method");

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"CustomViewAnnotation";
    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [objMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    if(!annotationView)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                      reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    }

    //annotationView.canShowCallout= YES;


    NSLog(@"Annotation Index = %lu",(unsigned long)[mapView.annotations indexOfObject:annotation]);
    Annotations *myCustomPinAnnot = (Annotations*)annotation;
    NSLog(@"Selected title = %@",myCustomPinAnnot.title);

    if ([myCustomPinAnnot.title isEqualToString:@" TOWER PLACE"]) {
        arrayFromArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSString *eff0 = [[allDataArray objectAtIndex:0] pinEfficiencyObjectClass];
        NSString *eff1 = [[allDataArray objectAtIndex:1] pinEfficiencyObjectClass];
        NSString *eff2 = [[allDataArray objectAtIndex:2] pinEfficiencyObjectClass];
        NSString *eff3 = [[allDataArray objectAtIndex:3] pinEfficiencyObjectClass];

        [self calculateEfficiency:eff0 andSecondEff:eff1 andThirdEff:eff2 andFourthEff:eff3];

        [arrayFromArray addObject:[allDataArray objectAtIndex:2]];
        [arrayFromArray addObject:[allDataArray objectAtIndex:1]];
        [arrayFromArray addObject:[allDataArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [arrayFromArray addObject:[allDataArray objectAtIndex:3]];

        joinString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"mais_",[self getColourCode:eff0 andSecondEff:eff1      andThirdEff:eff2 andFourthEff:eff3],@".png"];

        NSLog(@"Join String = %@",joinString); //JoinString is the image fetched from web service
        UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:joinString]];
        [imgV setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];

        annotationView.image = imgV.image;

    }
return annotationView;

}
```

i get a 4 pins with the respective images.

now when i click on a particular pin i am able to take the data to the next view but the image differs.
That is if i click on a pin with title say "abc", i successfully display the title on the next screen.
But if the image on the pin is for example red, the image on the next view is different.

Only the images of the first and last pin are being displayed correctly on the next view.

For the second it gives me the first image and for the third it gives me the image of last pin.

Weird.

my didSelectAnnotationCode.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    Annotations *annView = view.annotation; 
    NSLog(@"Pin title in callout = %@",annView.pinTitle);
    objOnClickPinView = [[onClickPinView alloc]initWithNibName:@"onClickPinView" bundle:nil];

    objOnClickPinView.pinTitleString = annView.pinTitle;

    [self presentViewController:objOnClickPinView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**Note: I don't need to display the calloutView. I need to directly navigate on click of mapPin.**

Comment: **viewForAnnotation** Show this method definition..?

Comment: how do you presenting the ann.image in the objOnClickPinView?

Comment: i send the join string to the next view ...and in the next view i break the join string to get the images and then set the images accordingly

Comment: that s hard to do like the way you are doing .? why don't you try to refer the image to the next view in the **didSelectAnnotationView**  as like title...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the error.
I am posting this answer only because if in the near future someone of you might face the same silly problem.

The join string i was passing to the next view was overridden by its previous, and therefore it contained dummy data.
I figured this out by putting the same code in

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
```

and using the

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

that how will the compiler come to know which pin was tapped.

Therefore i used 4 different joinStrings instead of one, and on checking the condition in the didSelect as

```
if ([annView.title isEqualToString:@"xyz"]) {
        objOnClickPinView.getColorCode = joinString1;
    }

else if...
```